# Enabling debugging content in REST API responses

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I'm designing a REST API. I'd like to provide to API caller *optional* debugging information in responses (e.g. execution times of some activities and internal details).

Let me give you an example of response:

```json
{
  "result": "XYZ",
  "details": [{
    "step": "FIRST_STEP",
    "executionTime": "12 ms"
  }, {
    "step": "SECONT_STEP",
    "executionTime": "12 ms"
  }, ...
  ]
}
```

Given that I want that the API caller explicitly asks for debugging information, I'm thinking that it may add an additional query parameter like `debug=true` to the call. BUT I don't know if there are common conventions. If you know some API guidelines and/or best practices that solve my doubt, any suggestion will be appreciated.